# How to replace a hole mathematical expression?

Tags: replacement

I have the following function:

**Input:**

```
f=-a n^2/v^2 +v/n
```

I want to Replace `v/n` by `v_new`

**Attempt:** *[Failed]*

```
f/. v/n -> v_new
```

**Desired output:**

```
-a/v_new +v_new
```

Comment: One imediate issue that I can spot is use of underscore _  in the variable you are trying to use to replace 'v/n'

Comment: As a general rule, structure replacement rules with the LHS of the rule to be as simple as possible to avoid having to handle multiple cases separately. For example, as pointed out in answer by @JasonB, instead of `v/n -> v2` use `v -> n*v2`

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon     Thanks! This helps

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify your replacement rule so that you aren't replacing `v/n->v2`, but replacing `v->n v2`

```
f = -a n^2/v^2 + v/n
(* -((5 n^2)/v^2) + v/n *)

f /. v -> n v2
(* -(5/v2^2) + v2 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

I do not know how to evaluate your eq. to the desired output. However if you use [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) in a following way you can replace 'v/n' term. Please see the implementation below. Also, please refer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395) link for information on basic syntax issues.

**Input**

```
-a*n^2/v^2 + v/n /. v/n -> v2
```

Where `v2` is the variable which is going to be used for replacement and `v/n` is going to be the term to be replaced.

**Output**

> -((a n^2)/v^2) + v2

**EDIT 1:**
*Format*

Comment: The main point here is that the replacement is not complete. When I replace v/n by v2 there shall be the output  -((a/(v2)^2) + v2 . This is the expectation, but what really happening is that: -((a n^2)/v^2) + v2. This is not the output I want

Comment: -a*n^2/v^2 + v/n /. {v/n -> v2, n^2/v^2 -> v2} - do you mean this?